# Do SAGA tools work on QGIS 3.10.7?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, saga

Is anyone successfully using SAGA tools in QGIS 3.10.7?

I have downloaded QGIS 3.10.7 on multiple PCs and a Mac. All of them have resulted in the same problem when I try to run SAGA tools. A message similar to:

> "The following layers were not correctly generated.
> C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_7cf0f5b0db874bb9a6b8fe84b44cb047/2a6b2113845f4739b4dec0f12c451504/C_PROF.sdat"
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
> more information about the execution of the algorithm."

I've downloaded QGIS from the QGIS Standalone Installer Version 3.14 (64bit) and the OSGeo4W Network Installer (64bit)

Here are images of the 'Log Messages Panel'

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not seeing anything in the log that suggests why the layers were not correctly generated. It ultimately generates a layer with reasonable looking values, but I am concerned about their accuracy given the warning.

More specifics:

- I have tried to run SAGA tools using an ASCII file and TIFF file.
- Files that I have tried range from ~250MB to 1.7GB
- I am using a projected coordinate system - EPSG:26919 - NAD83 / UTM zone 19N - Projected
- I have set the project CRS to match the layer CRS before attempting processing

Anyone successfully using SAGA tools with QGIS 3.10.7? If so, any ideas what is causing this problem for me?

Comment: I have an older version of QGIS (2.12.3 - Lyon). When I use the same SAGA methodology and data on QGIS (2.12.3), it does not say that, "The following layers were not correctly generated," like it does with QGIS (3.10.7). And, the values that are created with QGIS (2.12.3) and QGIS (3.10.7) are exactly the same. Should I ignore the message provided by QGIS (3.10.7) that "The following layers were not correctly generated." I am going to be publishing this data, so I want to be sure that the data are correct.

Comment: A friend who uses QGIS (3.10.7) told me he gets the same warning when running SAGA tools - "The following layers were not correctly generated." Could others please tell me if they are successfully/unsuccessfully using SAGA tools with QGIS (3.10.7). 3.10.7 is the long-term, stable release of QGIS and I think it would be good to know if SAGA tools work properly on this release. Here is a link to raster data if you need some to check with. https://unh.box.com/s/m7kiz5c980rre8ws285feoxfqfsf0z3q

Comment: The same warning is produced from the most recent, development version of QGIS (3.14.0)

Comment: *I don't have enough reputation to comment...*
I am also UNABLE to get SAGA tools to work with QGIS. (3.10.7, 3.12.1, 3.14.0) on a Mac running 10.14.6. The tool I am trying to use works intermittently. When it does work I get the same error you listed above. When it does not work it simply freezes until I force quit QGIS. I was using 'Natural Neighbor' on three sets of GPS points. It works on some data sets and not on others (all shapefiles in my case and working on the set with about 250 points but not on the other two with fewer points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an ongoing issue, at least since QGIS 3.6.0. Despite the warning, the values that are produced seem to be correct. Read this thread for a conversation on the topic. https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29346. It appears that similar warnings can be produced using GDAL through QGIS also.

As I commented above, I have performed the same SAGA calculations using QGIS 3.10.7, 3.14, and 2.12.3. QGIS 2.12.3 does not report any error, QGIS 3.10.7 and 3.14 do. Despite the error, all three versions result in the same values being produced.

Considering this and the conversation in the link provided suggesting that the values are correct and the warning is innocuous, I believe that the warning can be ignored and values can be trusted.

Comment: Unfortunately, not always. I'm trying to use the tool "Fill Gaps in Records" with QGIS 3.10.10 and the generated files are either not readable (shp) or incomplete (dbf)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen extensive reference to similar problems with SAGA tools in QGIS 3.* and I experience these myself for all SAGA tools I try, and despite trying the suggestions of not having spaces in file paths, creating a temp file, disabling "load upon completion," etc.  The log declares that outputs have been created, but the folder specified is empty.  Some of the OTB tools have a similar problem.

Some of the places where a similar issue has been discussed are here:

[QGIS (3.10.7) SAGA tools resulting in "The following layers were not correctly generated."](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365945/qgis-3-10-7-saga-tools-resulting-in-the-following-layers-were-not-correctly-g?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[QGIS 3.4.4 and 3.6 SAGA Tools all not working with same error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314355/qgis-3-4-4-and-3-6-saga-tools-all-not-working-with-same-error?rq=1)

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29346